# Declare Global/Site Wide Variable in ASP.Net VBHTML

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-2, razor-pages

After about a thousand years of building websites in ASP Classic, I am trying to learn ASP.Net using Razor. I am using Visual Studio 2012. Google seems to be of no help on some of these basic things (but, I probably just don't know the right question to ask). One of the absolute basic things I am struggling with right now is how to declare a variable that I can use across my website.

For example:

```
DIM DefaultColor AS String = "Green"
```

I have that in the `_AppStart.vbhtml` page and I try to access it using

```
 <p>@DefaultColor</p>
```

in the `Default.vbhtml`, but I get an error saying that `DefaultColor` is not declared.

- How and or where do I declare a variable that I can access across the website?
- If the `_AppStart.vbhtml` page is the right page, do I need to add something to the `default.vbhtml` or `_template.vbhtml` page to load it?

Comment: Welcome to the future! Are you using [tag:asp.net-mvc] or [tag:razor-pages]? The answer you get depending on the UI framework you are using may vary considerably. Do note, there is also a new kid on the block: `AspNetCore`, which also uses razor.

Comment: I am using Razor v2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I am not sure if ASP.NET Core is available for VB.NET. At least I tried to create a new project for VB.NET but the ASP.NET Core is not available. I will tell you how you can do it using the C# template.

You can use the TempData object in order to store and retrieve data. You can set a value like this:

```
@{
    TempData["Value"] = "Hello World";
}
```

Now you can display this value like this.

```
@TempData["Value"]
```

An other option is to create a static class which will contain the variable which will host the value.

```
namespace Sample
{
    public class MyStaticClass
    {
        public static string Value = "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

Now you can display the contents of the value like this:

```
@Sample.MyStaticClass.Value
```

You can also set a value and use it later.

```
Sample.MyStaticClsas.Value = "New Value";
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: So, do you add the TempData["Value"] = "Hello World"; in the _AppStart.vbhtml file?

Comment: In ASP.NET Core 2 C# template the file is called _ViewStart.cshtml. If you are planning to user ASP.NET Core, it is better to start working with C#.